# Water vapour collapse

Tags: thermodynamics

If you have closed volume of water vapor and make it condense by cooling or raising the pressure, it will collapse instantly. This is demonstrated in the collapsing can experiment 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsoE4F2Pb20
This effect also is the reason for cavitation.
But why does it collapse instantly? The condensation of a fraction of the vapor should both lower the pressure in the volume and raise the temperature by releasing some latent heat. Both effects should damp the collapse and not expedite it.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the video. As the water condenses, the internal pressure of the barrel goes down, until it is significantly below the external air pressure. However, since the barrel is made of steel, and is a clean cylinder, it can resist a great deal of external pressure.

Once the pressure difference becomes too much, the cylinder starts collapsing, which greatly reduces its strength, so it continues rapidly collapsing until the pressure difference is far less than it had been.

The suddenness of the collapse had nothing to do with suddenness of the phase change of the water; it was only because the barrel's structure failed. It's just as an above-ground pool can [suddenly fail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEGXDnMhd5A), even though there's nothing sudden about the water pressure within the pool.

Comment: It dont think so. This works even with an open can with the opening under water. The pressure drp is so sudden that the water is not sucked in quickly enouh to compensate the pressure drop  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08-Wi1rByAk

Comment: Nope: that's a different phenomena. As the water vapor cools, it starts pulling cold water in through the hole. The spray of water rapidly cools and condenses the vapor, which pulls in more cold water. The feedback loop rapidly condenses all the vapor and collapses the can.

Comment: If you're still not sure about that last video of the soda can, ask yourself why in such videos they always turn the can upside down before they plunge it in water.

Answer (score 0):

If the container is not rigid then the pressure keeps balanced with the exterior, so there is no (final) pressure drop !  But nothing is of duration zero (nor complete at 100.000%). Starting with the propagatation of the "refreshing" temperature (in metal and in vapor) causing the collapse, the mecanical time for the collapse of the metallic container, etc. And you'll have a bit of remaining vapor in the tank.